# Can we add regular expression in scrapy .xpath()

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

```
title = data.xpath("//*[@id='jsheadline_989615']/span/text()").extract()
name = data.xpath("//*[@id='js_item_989615']/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/strong[1]/text()")
        .extract()
price = data.xpath("//*[@id='js_item_989615']/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/strong[2]/text()")
        .extract()
print title, name, price
```

For above code I want to write a regular expression for `id`

```
title = data.xpath("//*[@id='([jsheadline_]+\d{5}[0-9])']/span/text()").extract()
```

Is not giving any result to me. I am using `xpath helper 2.0` on Chrome

Comment: for above code i want to write regular expression for id ie.                        title = data.xpath("//*[@id='([jsheadline_]+\d{5}[0-9])']/span/text()").extract()     but it not giving any result to me i m using xpath helper 2.0 version chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy uses `lxml` as xpath engine, you can register new namespaces in `lxml`:

```
from lxml import etree

def register_xpath_namespaces():
    fns = {
            'date':'http://exslt.org/dates-and-times',
            'dyn':'http://exslt.org/dynamic',
            'exsl':'http://exslt.org/common',
            'func':'http://exslt.org/functions',
            'math':'http://exslt.org/math',
            'random':'http://exslt.org/random',
            're':'http://exslt.org/regular-expressions',  # FOR REGEXP
            'set':'http://exslt.org/sets',
            'str':'http://exslt.org/strings'
    }
    for k,v in fns.iteritems():
        etree.FunctionNamespace(v).prefix = k

register_xpath_namespaces()
```

Then you can get title via xpath:

```
title = data.xpath("//*[re:match(@id, '[0-9]+')]/span/text()").extract()
```

<sub>**Note**: Please test it yourself.</sub>

Comment: thanks @kev but my question is can we add regular expression in that xpath because i want to take different value from  same pages with different id. ex: @id='js_item_989615'  @id='js_item_965788' like that

Comment: xml namespace can be any string, it may not a real url.

Answer (score 1):

`Scrapy` has [built-in support for regular expressions](http://egular-expressions) inside XPath expressions:

```
data.xpath("//*[re:test(@id, '[0-9]+')]/span/text()").extract()
```